# What is thermal capacity in a nuclear power plant?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I am looking at a nuclear powerplant reactor that has 3.2GW "thermal capacity" and 1GW "nameplate capacity".

**What does the thermal capacity entail? Is it how much heat the reactor produces?**

Comment: Conversion from heat to electricity is not 100% efficient.

Comment: You should read   https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Megawatts_thermal

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nameplate_capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermal capacity refers to the output of the *heat source* which in this case is the core of a nuclear reactor.

Nameplate capacity refers to the output of the *generators* which are being spun with steam turbines, which in turn are furnished with steam from water boiling in the reactor core.